# How to use "required" attribute within Angular directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using an AngularJS directive to generate two radio buttons. I'm hardcoding the "required" attribute into the directive template, but it doesn't behave as expected.

When no radio buttons are checked, it correctly displays this error message, as expected.

```
<p ng-show="form.$invalid">Error: the form is invalid.</p>
```

But it doesn't display this error message.

```
<p ng-show="form.gender.$invalid">Error: the gender input is invalid.</p>
```

Any idea why?

Please see the Plunker for details:

http://plnkr.co/edit/i5kVeX8WdrUbM83lT6O6?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your directive to validate input fields initially. You can do this by defining `$formatters` callback checking validity of the fields:

```
app.directive('dRadio', function() {
    return {
        require: '^form',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { model: '=ngModel' },
        template: '<input required type="radio" id="{{value}}" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}" ng-model="model"><label for="{{value}}">{{label}}</label>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            scope.name = attrs.name;
            scope.value = attrs.value;
            scope.label = attrs.label;

            ngModelController[attrs.name].$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
                ngModelController[attrs.name].$setValidity('required', !!scope.model);
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Note, that you also need to add `require: '^form'` rule.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/rac1RNNOWHs1wTnktJHE?p=preview

Comment: That seems to work. The only issue now is if I choose "I'm a female" first, it still says "Error: the form is invalid." Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the updated demo, I figured out correct approach. You should deal with "common" ngModelController for the group of inputs, retrieved from ngForm controller, by group name `attrs.name`.

Comment: That works great. Thanks! One tiny detail, I think ngModelController.gender.$setValidity should be ngModelController[attrs.name].$setValidity, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish by doing this way
[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/veN7UGdGTDgj9Rg5oR7Q?p=preview)

I changed the following line

```
<p ng-show="!test">Error: the gender input is invalid.</p>
```